# Where can I find information on the prosody of a poem?

Tags: poetry, resources

Where can I find out what the meters, feet, and stresses are in a poem? I found a [website](https://prosody.lib.virginia.edu/) where you can guess where they are, but the website doesn't provide answers.

Comment: Do you mean a reference work listing all poems and their meters? Or some sort of online tool for calculating it?

Comment: Any of those would work. An online tool would be very useful though.

Comment: That website **does** provide answers. And if you go through all the exercises the website provides, you should be able to do a pretty good job of scanning the poems yourself.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry) is a mess, but certainly provides lots of clues. The footer has a section with links to specific poetic meters.